Sending email in C# using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient and Rackspace SMTP
We recently moved our email addresses to be hosted at Rackspace.  I needed to update my C# code for sending email from our website using SMTP.  Doing some searches I found that the settings should be:

Outbound Secure SMTP:    secure.emailsrvr.com
Port:    465 or 587
SMTP Username:   Your full email address (name@domain.com)
SMTP Password:   Your mail account password

I set the port property of the SMTP client control to 465, but received an error that said "The server response was: 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: Access denied".  Then I made sure to set the EnableSsl property to true, but I still received and error of "System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed"

Switching the port to 587 solved the problem.  Even though the Rackspace support page said "465 or 587", 465 did not work, but 587 did.  Here is the C# code I used with all of the relevant settings:
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient sc = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("secure.emailsrvr.com");
sc.EnableSsl = true;
sc.Port = 587;
sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mailer@test.com", "*********");
sc.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
sc.Send(email);

